# Cadence cron schedule according to timezone

Tags: go, cadence-workflow

What is the timezone used by cadence by default?

How can we change cron expression according to timezone? eg if a user enters a cron schedule from a different timezone than the cadence's server timezone let say the user enters 1 pm every day in GMT + 5 then it should run at 9 am in the server( assuming cadence's server timezone is GMT only ).

I am using golang cadence client to write the workflows.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to rewrite the cron expression yourself before passing it to Cadence. Consider using an existing library like [cron-utils](https://github.com/jmrozanec/cron-utils) for this.